# Убрать секционирование для индекса в SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Имеется БД, в ней несколько таблиц. Секционирование поставлено на индекс. Как его отключить? Посоветовали пересоздать, попробовал, индекс не удаляется.

Comment: _"индекс не удаляется"_ Ошибку какую-то выдаёт или молча не удаляется?

Comment: @i-one я обновил вопрос

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что вы удаляете не индекс, а схему секционирования (partition scheme), которая используется. По [ссылке](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/50016/how-to-remove-the-sql-server-partitioning-implemen.html) есть пример запроса к системным каталогам, выполнив который, можно посмотреть какие таблицы и индексы используют схемы секционирования. Как убрать секционирование вам ссылку уже давали.

Comment: @propro17 Добавьте код ошибки в тело вопроса (кнопка [edit]) в виде текста, а не изображения.

Answer (score 1):

В свойствах секционированного индекса, в разделе Storage есть переключение между хранением индекса в Filegroup либо Partition scheme. Разумеется, после смены хранилища индекс будет пересоздан.